# newlib sscanf() throw hardfault exception in stm32

Tags: scanf, stm32, newlib

i use gcc compile my project, use the function sscanf() in main, the stack size is 4k, i debug the program in gdb, show VPUSH instruction throw the exception.

and i test the function sprintf(), it work nice. why the function sscanf() is not work in newlib for stm32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from STM32 F4 series, those controllers do not support floating point instructions, `vpush` being one of them.

The problem should be solved by compiling newlib with `-mfloat-abi=soft` (and not `softfp` or `hard`).